# Swift abstract return type of method

Tags: swift

I wanna to create a function that returns a value an array from the UserDefauts, like this:

```
func GetBool(name: String) -> Bool {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    return defaults.bool(forKey: name)
}

func GetBoolArray(name: String) -> [Bool] {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    return defaults.array(forKey: name) as? [Bool] ?? [Bool]()
}
```

But I don't wanna create a function for Bool, another for Int, another for CGFloat, etc.

What's the best way to abstract all functions (for Bool, Int, etc.) into one (one for single values, other for array values)?

Comment: Think generic: `func getArray<T>(name: String) -> [T]`

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
func GetValue(name: String) -> Any? {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    return defaults.value(forKey: name)
}

func GetValueArray(name: String) -> [Any] {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    return defaults.array(forKey: name) ?? [Any]()
}
```

Note that the first function needs to be unwrapped when used because the key you used might not match a value.
Also, I believe array for key works with NSArrays only so the first function would probably work for both cases for you.

Comment: how would I use it to retrieve a Bool array, for example? `let boolarray = GetValueArray(name: "arrayname") as! [Bool] ?? [Bool]()` ?

Comment: I would try and avvoid force unwrap at any cost. Either like this:
```let boolarray = GetValueArray(name: "arrayname") as? [Bool] ?? [Bool]()```
or like this: 
```var boolArray = [Bool]()
if let unwrappedBoolArray = GetValueArray(name: "arrayname") as? [Bool] {
   boolArray = unwrappedBoolArray
}```

Comment: @DcCoO Also please see my updated answer for the second function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Martin R, I discovered swift generics, this is what I was looking for

```
func GetValue<T>(name: String) -> T {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    return defaults.value(forKey: name) as! T
}

func GetArray<T>(name: String) -> [T] {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    return defaults.array(forKey: name) as? [T] ?? [T]()
}
```

Comment: The first one will *crash* if the user default has the wrong type or is not set. You should (almost ever) avoid `as!`

Comment: I will call every function correctly, I mean, I know that GetValue("abc") will return me an Int value, so I wont make var x: String = GetValue("abc")

Comment: Well, its your app. But are you always 100% that you know what kind of value has been stored for the key in any previous version of your app?

Comment: yes, I'm sure, I just wanted these functions to avoid writing `let defaults = ...... defaults.array(.... as.......` which is too long to write lots of times

Comment: @MartinR but tell me, how do I write to treat if the value doesnt exist ?